# Get content from different's div

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").click(function() {

        $("#ajax-content").html("<div id='loading'><img src='{THEME}/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");

        $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var location = this.href +" #answers";
        $("#ajax-content").load(location);

        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a id="answers" href="test1.html">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="answers" href="test2.html">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="ajax-content">This is default text, which will be replaced</div>
```

My question is, can I get contents from different div id for each link?
Somthing like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a id="answers1" href="test1.html">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="answers2" href="test2.html">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="ajax-content">This is default text, which will be replaced</div>
```

With my jQuery code, I can get content just from #answers. I need to get content for each link, from different div id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").on('click', function() {
        $("#ajax-content").html("<div id='loading'><img src='{THEME}/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");

        $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var location = this.href + ' #' + this.id; //use the ID here
        $("#ajax-content").load(location);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAbhU/1/)